# AVAudioPlayer can't play .caf file in /Documents when the app restart

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer to play audio of .caf file store in the sandbox of the simulator. When I run the program and play the audio of the file that I created just now, it works, but I can't play the audio of the files created when the application ran last time.

My code for playing the audio：

```html
if (self.audioURL != nil) {
        _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.audioURL error:nil];
        if (!_player) {
        } else {
            [_player setNumberOfLoops:0]; 
            [_player setDelegate:self];
            [_player play];
        }
    }
```

My `.caf` files are stored in the sandbox:

```
/Users/kiki/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2AF173A9-8C49-4F2E-9547-079AEDC0B020/data/Containers/Data/Application/EF2931D8-B498-4239-84AD-00525CA62F48/Documents
```

And the player didn't respond any error message, in other words, the methods of "`audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error" and "audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag`" not called.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please add the code you are using for playing the audio

Comment: I am wondering if it is the problem that I get no authority of accessing the files

Comment: How you created `self.audioURL` ?

Comment: I use Alamofire to download the .caf file, and it create the url automatically

Comment: I mean are you storing and retrieving the file url completely or manually calculating the path with file name ?

Comment: I store the file url to my sqlite

Comment: That's the problem, for each launching of your app, those guuid's will change, so the url will become invalid

Comment: @MidhunMP Thanks for the info abt guuid. So should we store the audio data in UserDefaults then? So we can play it whenever we want in the app

Comment: @Sha: No, you should dynamically determine the path of document directory and append your file name. Never depend on whole path, it will change on each execution of your app